# Proof that $\frac{b}{1+b} \|u-v\| > \|v\| - 1$ and $\|u-w\| \geq (1+b)^{-1} \|u-v\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, inequality, banach-spaces

Let $E$ is a Banach Space, let $u,v \in E$ and $w = \frac{v}{\|v\|}$ s.t. $\|u\|= 1 \leq \|v\|$. Taking $c = b/(1+b)$ suppose that $$\|u+v\|^2 + c^2 \|u-v\|^2 > 2 + 2\|v\|^2 \quad \quad (1) $$

I'm trying to proof that $\frac{b}{1+b} \|u-v\| > \|v\| - 1$ and $\|u-w\| \geq (1+b)^{-1} \|u-v\|$.

My attempt:

The first inequality follows from triangle inequality, indeed
$$ c^2 \|u-v\|^2 > 2 + 2\|v\|^2 - \|u+v\|^2 \geq 2+ 2\|v\|^2 - \|u\|^2 - \|v\|^2 - 2\|v\| $$
since $\|u\|=1$, follows
$$ c^2 \|u-v\|^2 > 1 + \|v\|^2 - 2\|v\| = (\|v\| - 1)^2$$
hence, $c \|u-v\| >\|v\| - 1$, where $c = \frac{b}{1+b}$.

The second inequality I can't see why it holds only using $(1)$.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the intent is that $b>0$ and that $c>0$. With that I mind, I would think that in the second inequality, it should be $1+b$ instead of $1-b$ (otherwise, for instance, the natural case $c=1/2$  leads to an impossible second inequality).

We have, using the triangle inequality and then the first inequality,
\begin{align}
\|u-v\|&\leq \|u-w\|+\|w-v\|=\|u-w\|+(\|v\|-1)\\ \ \\
&<\|u-w\|+\frac b{1+b}\,\|u-v\|.
\end{align}
Then
$$
\|u-w\|>\left(1-\frac b{1+b}\right)\,\|u-v\|=(1+b)^{-1}\,\|u-v\|.
$$